# Function's return value is unexpected

Tags: c

```
long long encrypt(int message,int n,int e)
{
long long s=pow(message,e);
return s%n;
}
```

When I try this:

```
        printf("%lli",encrypt(65,3233,17));
```

It prints out this:
-2631

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this...To be honest those are small values for now..I think I'll use larger values in the future

Comment: 65^17 is a rather big number... does it fit into a `long long`? What about the limits of `pow` itself?

Comment: I am not sure but if not can you answer on how to do this..I have to sometimes use much huger numbers

Comment: Obviously you will not be able to use built-in types. Which means that you will have to use custom libraries. And since you are going to do that, remember that **doing your own crypto is a sure path to unpleasant surprises**. Pick up a crypto library and you will have solved both problems without writing a single line of code.

Comment: Well the point is in trying to write my own crypto,even if it's not that good :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will do:

```
int encrypt(int message,int n,int e)
{
    int s = 1;
    while (e--) {
        s = ( s * message ) % n;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: It's not working really
It's giving 2000 something...I'm sure that's not the answer

Comment: The right answer is 2790, if that's helpful to you, @HasanSaad.

Comment: @HasanSaad, what do you expect to get? 2790 is very neat I think. You will get something less than 3233 for sure.

Comment: Oh sorry then..I got it wrong and i thought it'll be something really huge..sorry

Comment: Ok I checked the answer again somewhere and it's perfectly great..Thanks a lot.. This is the best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

A `long long` is probably 64 bits on your system.  The biggest (decimal) number you can put in it is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  You're trying to put 65<sup>17</sup> in one - that's 6,599,743,590,836,592,050,933,837,890,625.  Overflow!

You need to use some kind of big number library to do these kinds of operations with perfect precision.  There are many available - [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), for example.

Comment: Well can you help me on how to put a number like that(and it'll be better if I can put huger numbers :D)

Comment: Well which library do you think I should use for this?

Comment: Maybe you should do some research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

We have Theorem as follows in Mathmatics:
*(a*b)%p =(a%p*b%p)%p*
So we can get this:

*(a^e)%n=(a(e-1)%p*a%p)%p*

so we can get code like this:

```
int encrypt(int message,int n,int e)
{
    int result = 0;

    if(1 == e)
    {
       return message%n;
    }
    else
    {
       result = encrypt(message,n,e-1);
    }

    return (result%p * message%p)%p;

}
```